# Pass Razor Form data back to C# controller method as Model from bootstrap modal with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Ok, so I have a controller method defined as:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool ModalCreate([Bind(Include = "LastName,FirstName,EmailAddress,PhoneNumber,CustomerID,VendorID")] Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CorrActionPerson.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.Merge(globalUtils.HandleExceptions(ex));
        }

        // do stuff...

        return false;
    }
```

and I also have an AJAX method that I would like to use to post the user back from the bootstrap modal box to.  I am using Entity Framework 6 and MVC 5.

Here is what I have tried for the AJAX:

```
    let objModalForm = $('#newPersonModal form');

    let person = objModalForm.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: urlPrefix + '/Quality/CorrAction/Person/ModalCreate',
        data: { person: person },
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data === 'True') {
            //do other stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is something not working? What's your question?

Comment: The `WebMethod` attribute has to be used on a `static` method.

Comment: The question is I can get it to return to the controller method but it is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment says controller method, so the `[WebMethod]` attribute isn't needed.  Try changing the data property of the AJAX request to:

```
data: person,
```

MVC matches the properties of the Person class, but the parameter name of "person" has no significance.  The data passed up also needs to be a class, not an array, so also try to use the `serialize()` method instead:

```
//let person = objModalForm.serializeArray();
let person = objModalForm.serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This got me up and running!